# Use Ruby command line tool out of the box upon gem install

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I made a bash command line tool that I'd like to convert to Ruby.
I know that I'd have to use `OptionParser` and stuff to write the program, but I look at programs like rake and see that once you install the gem, it's ready to use immediately. Why is this? When I make a program with optparse I have to put it in my bin and give it access.

How can I have the user use it out of the box with mac or windows if I make it into a gem?

Thank you

Comment: There are many other (better in my opinion) command line gems for ruby like [`slop`](https://github.com/leejarvis/slop) (more lightweight) and [`thor`](http://whatisthor.com/) (much more detailed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gems can include executable files which are added to the user's `PATH` by RubyGems when installing the gem.

Usually, those scripts are put into the `bin` directory (or `exe` nowadays) of your gem. You can then specify in your gemspec that scripts in this directory should be treated as executables:

In your gemspec file, you can thus put something like this:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name        = 'my_awesome_gem'
  spec.version     = '0.0.1'

  spec.bindir      = 'bin'
  spec.executables = ['my_script']

  # ...
end
```

As for the script itself, you should make sure that it is marked as executable (i.e. `chmod +x bin/my_script` on Linux/Mac) and that it has the right shebang as its first line. Usually, it looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts 'Hello World'
```

You can learn more about adding executables to your gem in the [RubyGems guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable).

Finally, if you are creating your basic gem structure with the `bundle gem my_awesome_gem` command, it will automatically create a reasonable gemspec file and basic structure. Just put your scripts into the `exe` directory and everything should just work.

Comment: I did this and I needed to specify `exe` as the `spec.bindir`. Are you sure that `bin` is correct?

Comment: Traditionally, executable scripts to be exposed with the gem used to be put into the `bin` directory. Nowadays (and esp. with current `bundler` versions), those scripts tend to be put into an `exe` directory instead, with scripts in `bin` only being used for internal purposes during development of the gem. However, this is all just convention. You can name your directories whatever you like as long as it matches the config in your gemspec :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got everything working. This article helped as well: http://robdodson.me/how-to-write-a-command-line-ruby-gem/